# How to add several images onto a PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Argument 'link' is an array of images' links.

```
function genPDF_fromUrl(link) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text(80, 25, 'MAP001');

    const rtnimg = compute(doc, link);
    console.log(rtnimg)
    Promise.all(rtnimg).then((success) => {
        doc.save("map.pdf");
    });
    console.log("Finish hello PDF!")
}
function compute(doc, link) {       
    return link.map(l => {
        let x = 0;
        let y = 0;
        x += 10;
        y += 10;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var genImg = new Image();
            genImg.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            genImg.src = l;
            console.log("genimg: ", genImg);

            genImg.onload = function () {   
            console.log("doc: ", doc);  
                doc.addImage(genImg, 'PNG',  x, y, 100, 100);    
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

The result is always a PDF with only text 'MAP001', I am not sure why the image would not be shown.

Below is the console output:

```
genImg:  is a img tag like < img crossorigin=​"anonymous" src=​"https:​/​/​cors.now.sh ... a link" >

rtnimg : (33) [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]

Finish hello PDF!

doc:  {internal: {…}, addPage: ƒ, setPage: ƒ, insertPage: ƒ, movePage: ƒ, …}
```

Below is my successful attempt of printing only a image on PDF.

```
function genPDF_fromUrl(link) {
        var genImg = new Image();
        genImg.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        genImg.src = link[0];

        genImg.onload = function () {    
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.setFontSize(40);
        doc.text(80, 25, 'MAP001');
        doc.addImage(genImg, 'PNG',  0, 0, 100, 100);         
        doc.save("map.pdf"); 
        }      
}
```

Seem like "var doc = new jsPDF();" has to be in onload function but I cannot do that for multiple images.

Comment: Does everything seem to be fine from the `console.log()`'s and give the expected output?

Comment: Yes, rtnimg gives back promise with status 'resolve'.

Comment: Have you tried adding some `console.log()`'s in your `compute()` function where you try add the images? Checking `genImg` ect...? Please update your question and explain what you have done to debug and try identify the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the PDF creation, and then waiting for each image. Instead of doing such way, my proposal is to preload all images and wait for a callback when all images have been downloaded and are ready to print in jsPDF by invoking the `addImage` function.

I did it in following way some time ago, as a part of a more complex jsPDF plugin

```
function Picture(src) {
    this.src = src;
    this.img = null;
}

function Preloader() {
    this.pictures = [];
    this.onpicturesloaded = null;
}

Preloader.prototype.setPicture = function(src) {
    var id = src.split("/").pop().split(".")[0].toLowerCase();
    this.pictures[id] = new Picture(src);
    return this.pictures[id];
};

Preloader.prototype.loadPictures = function() {
    var self = this, pictures = self.pictures, n = 0;
    for(var id in pictures) {
        if(pictures.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            var pic = self.pictures[id];
            n++;
        }
    }
    for(var id in pictures) {
        if(pictures.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            var pic = self.pictures[id];
            var decrease = function(e) {
                if(--n == 0) {
                    self.onpicturesloaded();
                }
            }
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                var pic = self.pictures[this.alt];
                pic.img = this;
                decrease();
            };
            img.alt = id;
            img.src = pic.src;
        }
    }
};
```

I'm using the *stripped filename* as `ìd` to get directly the associated image, for that reason there is this slightly overhead of the double loop inside the `loadPictures` function, if you find this too bad, feel free to change it to a true array, where you can get directly the picture count as `pictures.length`.

This `id` is then also used in jsPDF as `alias` for each image, to speed up the whole process, whereby the full image path is stored instead in `picture.src`.

This is (more pr less) the usage of all that stuff above:

```
var pl = new Preloader();
pl.setPicture("pdf/a.jpg");
pl.setPicture("pdf/b.jpg");
pl.setPicture("pdf/c.jpg");

pl.onpicturesloaded = function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var pic = pl.pictures["a"];
    doc.addImage(pic.img, "jpg", 10, 10, 100, 100, pic.img.alt, "FAST");
    // add more images, print text, and so on
    doc.save('mydocument.pdf');
};  
pl.loadPictures();
```

Please note, this is just an extract on-the-fly of that jsPDF plugin, without some parts which i needed for example, to draw inside a `canvas` and add on the fly the picture data to the PDF.

So, I am sure this can be further simplified and stripped down, but anyway, you can get the idea.